# Distribution function of X-Y for normally distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I have two independent normally distributed random variables $X,Y\sim \cal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and want to calculate the distribution of $X-Y$.
I tried with $F(z)=P(X-Y \leq z)$ but failed. Does anyone has an idea how I approach it?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? If so, do you know a general result about the distribution of a *linear combination* of **independent** normal random variables? You can see here for example: https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/172/.

Comment: Yes they are independent, thanks.

Comment: If I use this rule, then is $X-Y\sim \cal N(0,2\sigma^2)$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! Greetings Holly